# How can I reproduce this tree diagram?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, trees, forest, qtree

I want to reproduce the tree diagram shown below. My major problem is how to put text (Yes/No/Exposure...) next to the lines.

[image: , what i]

Comment: Hardly without any effort :-). For putting YES/NO labels at nodes you can use separate nodes, something like this ` ... child{ node (EX) [<style>] {Experimental study}} ...` and after tree `\node[above right=of EX] {Yes}`. More demanding is construction of tree, saying i rash, probably the easiest way will be hybrid between tree and standard TikZ picture ... And welcome to SE!

Comment: Welcome! Sine the tree isn't a problem, just post the code for that and somebody will be happy to show you how to add the labels. If you are not being altogether honest in your question - either with us or with yourself - **forest** could do this relatively easily. I would have no idea how to do it in **qtree** or using **tikz-trees** without a lot of messing around. **tikz-qtree** could also do it fairly straightforwardly, although it is not as powerful as **forest** and I could be mistaken about its capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details are left as an exercise to the reader.... Focus is on the topic of the question i.e. adding labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2.5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    draw,
    l sep+=2.5mm,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}% style for labels can go here
  }
  [Text
    [Query?
    [Option A, edge label={node[pos=.75, left]{Yes}}, l sep+=5mm, for children={circle, inner sep=1pt, edge path={\noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};} }
        [a]
        [b]
        [c, edge label={node[midway, right, align=left]{Something\\Something else\\Yet another thing}}]
      ]
      [Option B, edge label={node[pos=.75, right]{No}}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

`edge label` adds the labels in the usual way nodes are added as part of path specifications.

[image: add labels]

## EDIT

Here's the code you posted in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289797/), tidied up a bit and with multiline nodes enabled. I've defined a couple of styles to save typing and to make adding the Yes/No labels easier.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  my edge label/.style={
    if n=1{
      edge label={node[pos=.75, left]{Yes}}
    }{
      edge label={node[pos=.75, right]{No}}
    }
  },
  my circle/.style={circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum width=60pt, anchor=center},
  light grey/.style={fill=gray!20},
  dark grey/.style={fill=gray!60},
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2.5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    draw,
    l sep+=2.5mm,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge={font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
    align=center,
    light grey
  }
  [Did investigator\\assign exposures?, for children={dark grey}
    [Observational study, my edge label
      [Ramdom allocation?, for children={my circle}
        [Ramsomised\\controlled\\trial, my edge label]
        [Non-\\ramsomised\\controlled\\trial, my edge label]
      ]
    ]
    [Observational study, my edge label
      [Comparison group?, for children={dark grey}
        [Analytical\\study, my edge label
          [Direction?, l sep+=5mm, s sep+=25pt, dark grey,
            for children={%
              my circle,
              edge path={%
                \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
              },
            }
            [Cohort\\study, edge label={node[midway, left, align=left]{Exposure - Outcome}}]
            [Case-\\control\\study, edge label={node[pos=.9, left, align=left]{Exposure - Outcome}}]
            [Cross-\\sectiuonal\\study, edge label={node[midway, right, align=left]{Exposure and\\\hspace*{2.5em}outcome at\\\hspace*{5em}the same time}}]
          ]
        ]
        [Descriptive\\study, my edge label
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image: modified code with multiline nodes]

Comment: you are good soul and big propagator of use of the forest package :-)

Comment: @cfr I have a problem: I'm trying to use multiples lines in the nodes. In your example, if I add \\ after any node, e.g. `Query?\\Query?` it does not show two lines. it shows: `Query?Query?`  all together in the same line. Why? Help please

Comment: @J.Gatica Just add `align=left` or `align=center` or `align=right` inisde the argument of `for tree` and then **forest** will set up all nodes to allow multiple lines broken by `\\ `. Alternatively, you can say `text width=<some width>` and have the lines broken automatically, but I find manual breaks tend to produce better results.

Comment: @J.Gatica Please see edit. I took the code you posted, added the `align` and set up some styles to make it easier to format things consistently and add the shadings etc. Hope this helps ;).

Comment: Wow! that's perfect! yes, It helps a lot. :)
@cfr you are the man!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Well here's the diagram almost finished. Thank you @cfr, your example was perfect.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
edge path={
  \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2.5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
},
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
draw,
l sep+=2.5mm,
font=\sffamily,
edge={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}% style for labels can go here
  }
[Did investigator assign exposures?
    [Observational study, edge label={node[pos=.75, left]{Yes}}
        [Ramdom allocation?
            [Ramsomised controlled trial, edge label={node[pos=.75, left]{Yes}}]
            [Non-ramsomised controlled trial, edge label={node[pos=.75, right]{No}}]]]
    [Observational study, edge label={node[pos=.75, right]{No}}
        [Comparison group?
            [Analytical study, edge label={node[pos=.75, left]{Yes}}
                [Direction?, l sep+=5mm, for children={circle, inner sep=1pt, edge path={\noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};} }
                    [Cohort study, edge label={node[midway, left, align=left]{Exposure - Outcome}}]
                    [Case-control study, edge label={node[midway, left, align=left]{Exposure - Outcome}}]
                    [Cross-sectiuonal study, edge label={node[midway, right, align=left]{Exposure and\\outcome at\\the same time}}]
  ]]
            [Descriptive study, edge label={node[pos=.75, right]{No}}
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]